# regex for encapsulating v4 subnet mask and v6 prefix length

Tags: c++, regex, networking

I want a regular expression that can encapsulate both ipv4 subnet mask and ipv6 prefix length(1-128) .
I was thinking of expanding the following ptype to include the prefix length as well
PTYPE name="IP_ADDR"

```
pattern="(((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"
help="IP address AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD where each part is in the range 0-255"/>
```

the new pattern would look something like this .

```
pattern="((((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)) | (12[0-8]| 1[01][0-9] | [01]?[0-9][0-9]?))"
```

Is the above pattern right? Can someone suggest a better way to write the pattern?

Comment: If you already don't know if it is correct, that might be a hint this is the wrong way to go. I'm not even going to try and work out if that is correct. I've seen far worse, but how long do you think it will be before someone else comes along and has to understand it, or worse, change it?

Comment: Im new to it and this is the first regex im writing . not sure if it'll work or not

Comment: @SumitDas: www.rubular.com

Comment: (((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))|(12[0-8]| 1[01][0-9]|([1-9][0-9]?)

Comment: 300 is also accepted in the above expression . I believe it is due to ([1-9][0-9]? towards the end of the expression . My intention was to allow a single digit number [1-9] or a two digit number [1-99] . Can anyone tell why 300 is also accepted and the fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out by now, but the only real problem with your regex was that you did not specify a boundary. So, as you said in the comments, 300 would result in a match. This is because it matched the 30. If you added a word boundary `\b` then your match would work:

```
\b(12[0-8]|1[01][0-9]|([1-9][0-9]?))\b
```

Would only match 1 to 128. This works because it only allows the match to succeed if the match is preceded by a word boundary. 300 now fails because 30 is followed by a 0 rather than a word boundary.

I would simplify this to:

```
\b([1-9][0-9]?|[1][0-2][0-8])\b
```

In the case of an ipv6 address which is in the form:

```
<address>/<subnet mask>
```

Then the above regexes would still work because / is not a word character (is a boundary). But, if you specifically wanted to check for a preceeding `/` then you would do:

```
(?<=/)([1-9][0-9]?|[1][0-2][0-8])\b
```

`(?<=/)` is a positive lookbehind. It makes sure that the match is preceded by a `/`. Note that it is a zero length assertion which means that is not counted as part of the match, so your match will still just contain the subnet number.